# How do I crop the top and bottom of a video with hidden overflow?

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I am a beginner. I want to embed a video ([https://www.pexels.com/video/bartender-making-a-cocktail-3772392/]) with full width, but cropped top and bottom.

My CSS doesn’t work. The video doesn't change at all. Do I need to make a class in the div or an id in the video in html?

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  clip: rect(300px,0px,300px 0px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77672744.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clip-path`.

```css
video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.d1 video {
  clip-path: polygon(0 33%, 100% 33%, 100% 67%, 0 67%);
  margin: -18.6% 0;
}

.d2 video {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Clipped with a rectangular path</p>
<div class="d1">
  <video controls playsinline>
    <source src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77672744.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<p>Clipped with a non-rectangular path</p>
<div class="d2">
  <video controls playsinline>
    <source src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77672744.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However now the overlay text doesn't show atop the video unfortunately. But I will keep the clip-path in mind